# How to change the css of template in django?

Tags: python, css, django, image, static

I import a bootstrap template in django, the index.html is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Business Casual - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/business-casual.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="brand">university search</div>
<div class="address-bar">3481 Melrose Place | Beverly Hills, CA 90210 | 123.456.7890</div>
```

...

All my staticfiles in the folder static , the setting.py file is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I want to modifie the image of bacground of template but doesn't work , the css file is :

```
body {
font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
background: url('/home/hadoop/PROJET/static/img/theboatthatrocked.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cov
```

but it does not change anything, you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this tutorial:[Config static files in Django projects](https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupstaticdjangowebpageresources.html)